# How to modify TestNG/Allure (@Test(description), @Description, @TmsLink) values based on DataProvider supplied test parameters

Tags: java, reflection, testng, allure, testng-dataprovider

Given a TestNG test class with dataProvider and Allure for reporting, it is required to modify Allure's report to have a (@Test(description), @TmsLink,  @Description) values depending on DataProvider.

Is there a simple way to do it?

Note: 
I tried changing test name by using ITest interface, but has no effect on Allure report, I need TestNG test description and Allure @Decription & @TmsLink values modified.

Answer (score 1):

```
@BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
public void BeforeMethod(Method method, Object[] testData){
    TmsLink tmsLink = method.getAnnotation(TmsLink.class);
    Description description = method.getAnnotation(Description.class);
    Test test = method.getAnnotation(Test.class);

    changeAnnotationValue(tmsLink, "value", "<GET FROM testData>");
    changeAnnotationValue(description, "value", "<GET FROM testData>");
    changeAnnotationValue(test, "description", "<GET FROM testData>");
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static Object changeAnnotationValue(Annotation annotation, String key, Object newValue){
    System.out.println("BEFORE annotation: " + annotation);
    Object handler = Proxy.getInvocationHandler(annotation);
    Field f;
    try {
        f = handler.getClass().getDeclaredField("memberValues");
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
    f.setAccessible(true);
    Map<String, Object> memberValues;
    try {
        memberValues = (Map<String, Object>) f.get(handler);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
    Object oldValue = memberValues.get(key);
    if (oldValue == null || oldValue.getClass() != newValue.getClass()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    memberValues.put(key,newValue);
    System.out.println("AFTER annotation: " + annotation);
    return oldValue;
}
```

I managed to change Allure `@Description` and `@TmsLink` and TestNG `@Test.description`, but Allure still gets TestNG `@Test.description` before changing it, so I still need to update @Test.description before Allure captures it .

Comment: have you found any solution for this case?